# Что дает Linux для веба, чего не дает Windows?

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, linux

В смысле, что можно в Linux сделать такого, чего нельзя сделать в Windows? В тематике web? Просто словесные примеры приведите, если вообще какое-либо отличие в возможностях есть. Часто слышу такое выражение "в Linux можно сделать гораздо больше, чем в в Windows". А что именно сделать?

Comment: Grammar nazi негодует. Пишите правильно.

Comment: Что значит реализовать? ОС -- это среда для исполнения программ. Просто две разные платформы.

Comment: "А что именно сделать?" -- Видимо харакири. Вообще возможны нюансы по производительности (как в плюс, так и в минус), но в принципе возможности от ОС не зависят, основные инструменты под Linux многоплатформенные (в отличие от IIS)

Comment: Следовательно ничего существенного кроме производительности и нету?

Comment: Очень удобно скриптовать и автоматизировать рутинные вещи.

Проще и очевидней работать с правами доступа.

Comment: 3. В Windows нет системы прав доступа к файлам и папкам.
4. В Windows нет возможности поставить квоты.
5. В Linux файловая система лучше и быстрее, подсчет/расчет быстрее.
6. В Linux много bash команд, которые существенно помогают в разработке АСУ.

Comment: Как много нового и интересного! А где-нибудь эти пункты расшифрованы?
Вывод: ответ не по существу, провокация холивара.

Comment: Многие вещи сделать в Линуксе проще. Не то чтобы их нельзя сделать в Windows, просто это сложнее и/или неудобнее.

Comment: Уважаемый, setter, вы пишите полный бред.

Comment: > Что дает Linux для веба, чего не дает Windows?
производительность

Answer (score 14):

Можно подумать кроме бесплатности и открытого кода больше ничего нет.

Как минимум это простота в настройке окружения для разработки.

К примеру установка php+mysql+apache в винде занимает гораздо больше времени и плясок с бубном, чем какой-нибудь

```
apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2.
```

Comment: Ога, с апачем согласен. А какая-нибудь библиотечка, зависимая от двух других, каждая из которых зависима от 5 других, из которых ни одна не установлена, и все это по SSH - во какая простота. Особенно на каком-нибудь CentOs и одну из библиотек можно найти только на китайском серваке, у которого скорость скачивания 2кб/сек и пинг 5 сек.

Comment: И всетаки Windows или Linux? Ответ - каждый выбирает что ему угодно - нежелателен...

Comment: Шадов, я тогда даже боюсь представить как такое доставлять в винде...

Comment: @1101_debian в винде как правило можно скачать .msi или бинарник, который все скачает либо объяснт, почему на этой платформе это работать не будет.

@new_russian_man смотря что вы имеете в виду под веб-разработкой. Сайты проще делать на лине просто потому, что большинство мануалов ориентируются на линь и он более распространен + бесплатен. Серьезные нагруженные _прибыльные_ проекты лучше делать на вин-сервере. Как минимум потому, что за отказ оси работать мелкософт несет перед вами ответственность. Опенсорсеры никем не контролируются и ни за что не отвечают.

Comment: Ну если есть бинарник который все объяснит, то все хорошо, но тот пакет который вы привели в пример скорее всего вообще придется собирать руками =)

Comment: >Как минимум потому, что за отказ оси работать мелкософт несет перед вами ответственность

БРЕД! В лиценз. соглашении M$ сразу же отказывается от любых видов ответственности, связанных с неработоспособностью ПО у его приобретшего.

>в винде как правило можно скачать .msi или бинарник, который все скачает либо объяснт, почему на этой платформе это работать не будет.

Не согласен. Какое-нибудь сообщение об ошибке в духе 'can't load dll blablabla' делу не поможет. Софт под Windows если и пишет файлы протокола, то или не очень информативно, или пихает эти файлы в самые нетривиальные места.

Comment: Также очень радует необходимость качать over 100MB библиотек и фреймворков для утилит весом не более 20МБ. Вроде .NET 3.5. 4.0, конечно, пожали, но все равно смешно. А в дистрибутив их впихивать тоже дурной тон.

Comment: «Серьезные нагруженные прибыльные проекты лучше делать на вин-сервере.»
Скажите это Яндексу и Гуглу.

Comment: У яндекса и гугла прибыль с одного пользователя __огромна__. Если вы понимаете, что я хотел сказать)

ЗЫ: я не считаю прибыль с рекламы адекватной прибылью вообще. Это очень долгоживущая пирамида, продается __ничего__. Т.о., я говорю о проектах, не паразитирующих на товарах, а производящих(представляющих производителя) товар/услугу их или хотя бы продающих __напрямую__. Их мало, ага.

Comment: Нельзя ли пример web-проекта, производящего чего-либо, ну хотя бы пиво? Если лицензия недорогая, я бы на своём компе поставил. Даже под винды.

Comment: > А какая-нибудь библиотечка, зависимая от двух других, каждая из которых зависима от 5 других, из которых ни одна не установлена

@Sh4dow, откройте для себя gentoo :)

Comment: Блин, да мне не нужны эти пляски с бубном. Как пользователю мне нравится, что большинство моих действий автоматизировано и я не с тетриса в инете сижу, чтоб меня разница в нагрузке 10% волновала. Как программиста меня радует, что по своему вопросу я могу просто позвонить в ТП, а не полночи сидеть, перебирая комбинации параметров и потом найти на шведском блоге школоло-быдлокодера, переведенном гугл-транслейтом, что надо было дописать параметр "-а" при установке, которого нет в документации.

@alexlz линух пиво тоже не производит. И не придирайтесь, есть мнформационные товары/услуги.

Comment: Разумеется, автоматизация под виндами уже не тот ужас, что надцать лет назад, но всё же. А "просто позвонить в ТП" да ещё для каких-то шибко замороченный случаев -- "не верю". И уж насчёт веб в производстве: ну ляпнули не подумав, ну бывает...

Comment: а мне больше нравится когда сыплется стопмалопонятный, но информативный выводи о сборке, с детальным указанием ошибки, а в венде запустил екзешник, установка идет - и хлоп, какая-то ошибка, без описания и выбор cancel, abort, retry. все. и хрен его знает что делать. Под wp7 ошибки это вообще красота - error 0xabcd00fe - все. И вот вы уже кагбе и рады поплясать с бубном, ан нет, плясать-то некуда...

Answer (score 7):

Реально Linux в отличие от Windows дает две вещи (как вообще, так и для веба).

1. Бесплатность операционной системы. Что при масштабировании вширь, когда наращивается количество установок, имеет существенное значение в плане капитальных затрат.
2. Открытость исходного кода. Что при необходимости дает возможность изучать и модифицировать код операционной системы.

Comment: Про модификацию и так всем известно. Тут рассматривается тема спецификации. Есть ли что то особенное в линуксе для web разработки или нет? помимо бесплатности.

Comment: 1. Платность. Линупс стоит денег. Видимо там немного допилена. В любом случае бесплатно ничего годного нет.

2. В этом коде никто ничего не понимает. Вдобавок эта обфускация в виде макро изза переносимости.

Comment: 1. "Линупс стоит денег. " -- это как? Кому? Хотелось бы примеры (стоимость носителя, стоимость доставки/интернет трафика -- не считаем. Это величины необязательные -- "у товарища на флешку записал")
2. "Никто" -- перебор, хотя те, кто "понимает" в данном случае не всчёт, "обфускация" -- наезд, в остальном -- согласен

Comment: "В этом коде никто ничего не понимает. " - не говорите ерунды. Если вам и вашему окружению не хватает для этого квалификации, то не надо других-то оскорблять. Я даже больше скажу: в некоторых конторах не только понимают, но и пишут патчи на ядро специально для своих проектов. Например, яндекс патчит сетевой стек FreeBSD (по крайней мере, так они говорили пару лет назад).

Comment: я даже как-то собеседовался у паренька, который невзначай так рассказал как нашел баг в глибсе и правил его целых два дня =)

Comment: if (userName.equals("Indy")) obfuscateCodeImmediately() ;  :))

А кто такой васм?

Про обработку прерываний вот не надо. Всё дело в эффективности. трап-обработка может и выглядит красивее, но так ли эффективна?

Comment: Indy, уважайте других - наконец-то начните писать без грОмматичесГих АшЫпоК. Ну, пАжАлУСтА!

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я заметил при общении с Линукс, там можно работать с вебом более низкоуровнево, т.е. там нет такого ограничения в непосредственном доступе к сети (и не только). Windows же требует обращения к посредникам, коими являются компоненты оси.

Comment: > Насколько я заметил при общении с Линукс, там можно работать с вебом более низкоуровнево

NT модульная система. Это значит что есть множество всяких подсистем, которые посредники и позволяют вообще про железо не задумываться. Или вы хотите с железом самостоятельно работать, так зачем это нужно.

Comment: Например, чтоб непосредственно обращаться к ядру или той же сетевой карте. Или любому сисадмину это всё равно? Ерунда. Если в NT попадает червь или руткит, он изменяет ваши любимые подсистемы на свой лад. С Linux'ом такое не проходит. Вот зачем. Не нравится -- могу привести ещё кучку примеров, где работа с железом практически напрямую важнее всяких там модулей.

Comment: > С Linux'ом такое не проходит.

Не проходит потомучто никто под эту поделку не кодит. Что принципиально мешает малварю перепилить ядро ?

Comment: "Например, чтоб непосредственно обращаться к ядру или той же сетевой карте" - ну и зачем это нужно?? Это же безумие полное. Это уничтожит переносимость, поэтому нормальные люди не будут заниматься такой ерундой. Что же до червя, то это вообще непонятно к чему..

Answer (score -2):

Веб разработчикам, например серверным программистам, можно работать и на Linux. А вот как быть с front-end стороной, которую нужно постоянно тестировать в оригинальных ИЕ (не эмуляторах). Тут без винды не обойтись. А как быть asp.net разработчикам, линукс им не подходит.

Comment: На лигухе замечательно работает ASP .NET и ASP .NET MVC. 

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Comment: 1. От первоначального вопроса тихо-тихо уходим (да и Бог с ним, с вопросом, и с вопрошающим тоже). Холивар есть холивар!
2. Чем работа IE под wine отличается от работы под windows? (Просто интересно)

Comment: Слава богу, что недоступны :) А под wine по идее должны работать как родные. Но главное отличие работы IE под wine в том, что он там толком не работает. Это большое чудо, если вам удастся запустить его там.

Comment: "он там толком не работает" - кажется это его нормальное поведение =)

ну а откинув юмор таки скажу что нормально работает, ну сносно =)

если ставить через winetricks, то там доступен уже и восьмой

Comment: 1101_debian, по прежнему считаю что на данный момент asp.net плохо работает на linux исходя из собственного опыта.

Answer (score -2):

Если смотреть в ракурсе серверов и платформу PHP, то в линухе он работает в 10 раз быстрее виндового апача и в 3 раза быстрее виндового IIS.